# Best way to doing this in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

db.post

```
{user:'50001', content:...,},
{user:'50002', content:...,},
{user:'50003', content:...,},
{user:'50001', content:...,},
{user:'50002', content:...,},
```

db.catagory

```
{user:'50001', type:'public',...}
{user:'50002', type:'vip',...}
{user:'50003', type:'public',...}
```

What I want, is pickup the post of user what `type:public`.

I can do it like:

```
publicUsers = db.catagory.distinct(user, {type:'public'})
db.post.find({user: {$in: publicUsers }}).sort({_id:-1})
```

or use lookup in aggregate.

and output

```
{user:'50001', content:...,},
{user:'50003', content:...,},
{user:'50001', content:...,},
```

Is that some other better way to do this faster?

---

Consider of the large request situation, should I create a new db like post_public for finding?

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation pipeline is your best bet. It's quite performant, as it's intended for just these types of situations.

*Another Edit*

Ok, this is the best solution I have, but it has some [limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#data) set by Mongo.

- Firstly, a sort operation on *non-indexed* fields cannot use more than 100MB of RAM. That's quite a bit of space for text based posts, but something to be aware of (*there's a workaround that uses disk space if needed, but it will slow down the operation*).
- Second, and more relevant in this case, Mongo sets a hard cap on the size of a *single* document to 16MB. Given that you wanted the posts in a *single* array, a large dataset can potentially pass that ***if no limits on the output are imposed***. If you decide you don't want all posts in a *single* array, by removing the last three stages of the pipeline ($group, $addFields, and $project), the result will be the sorted posts each within their own document. You will need to limit the number of documents manually to get the *n* number of posts you want if you go that route. IMO, you should do this. Those last three stages add additional processing burden but offer very little practical benefit on the output. The only difference is iterating over a nested array, vs iterating over the root array.

```
db.categories.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    user: 1,
    type: 1
  }}, 
  {$match: {
    type: "public"
  }}, 
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'posts',
    localField: 'user',
    foreignField: 'user',
    as: 'userPosts'
  }}, 
  {$unwind: {
    path: "$userPosts",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
  }}, 
  {$sort: {
    "userPosts.posted": -1,
  }}, 
  {$group: {
    _id: "public",
    posts: {
      $push: "$userPosts"
    }
  }}, 
  {$addFields: {
    "latestPosts": {
      $slice: ["$posts", 5]
    }
  }}, 
  {$project: {
    posts: 0
  }}
]);
```

You'll access the resulting posts like so:

```
.then(result => {
  let latestPosts = result[0].latestPosts;
});
```

---

*Edit*

I built a mock database and came up with this solution:

```
db.categories.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        user: 1,
        type: 1,
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        type: "public"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $concat: ["$user", "-", "$type"]
        },
        user: {
            $first: "$user"
        },
        type: {
            $first: "$type"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        user: -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 10
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'posts',
        localField: 'user',
        foreignField: 'user',
        as: 'userPosts'
    }
}]);
```

The result will be an array of objects representing each unique user-type combo with the type specified in the $match filter. The object will contain a child array with all the posts made by that user. All the users will be sorted ind descending order and limited to ten.

If all you want is a single operator to get distinct values from categories:

```
db.categories.aggregate([{$project: {
  _id: 0,
  user: 1,
  type: 1
}}, {$group: {
  _id: {$concat: ["$user","-","$type"]},
  user: {$first: "$user"},
  type: {$first: "$type"}
}}]);
```

The goal is to first filter out the users with non-public types so they don't appear in the result, join the posts belonging to that user to a new field called "user_posts", and then sort all the users in ascending order. I don't know the entire structure of your database so my specific example may not be the best fit, but it would be a good starting point.

---

*Edit*

Some other ways to increase performance for large amounts of data:

1. By querying in pieces. Say for example you're displaying paginated user posts. Then you would only need to query the posts for the page currently being viewed. You can reduce any noticeable loading times by pre-fetching the next few pages as well.
2. Using a "virtual" list. This will display every post in one long list, but only fetch a certain size chunk that is currently being viewed, or will soon be viewed. Similar to the first pagination example. If you're familiar with the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) in Android development, that's the idea.
3. Restructuring the way posts are stored in your database. It would be a much faster operation if Mongo didn't need to iterate through so much unrelated data when looking for posts of a specific user or type. The solution is to store posts nested below a common ancestor, such as their poster, or their view type. This does mean that you may have duplicate entries spread between documents. This is one of the inherent downsides of a no-SQL database. You will need to find a solution for handling synchronizing the documents spread throughout the database.
4. Creating a new index on document fields that you use to sort your array. Indices help Mongo organize the documents internally for more efficient searches.
5. Running a heavy query once, then [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html)-ing the result. In this way you can store the result of expensive operations in a more permanent fashion than a simple cache.
6. A variant of number 5 is to $out the result of a large sorting operation, and then continuing to insert *new* entries at the end of the now sorted collection.

Comment: This is really an new way. But when I run it, it's very slow, because there is thousands public users and million posts. In other side, I want output the post data in sort by _id, so it looks a far way.

Comment: There are some [performance optimizations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) to improve efficiency. A good place to start is the $project operator to remove some data, I'll add it to my example. There is a limit to the performance you can squeeze out though, MongoDB isn't a relational database so it really isn't optimized for heavy joins like that. Migrating a db is a pain, but SQL would likely give better performance. Alternatively, you can nest a user's posts within a related document. That would be faster than iterating through millions of posts.

Comment: I've tried add $limit to the result, it is fast. I think it is maybe because of aggregate return a cursor, like a generator. But it is still a problem of sort the posts, so I have to start the aggregate in db.post[sort the post, lookup same user's type, and match], but it is not best enough for me.

Comment: Is that any way to return a user list which {$match:{type:'public'}}, and directly contain in db.post.aggregate, is that any function can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes you could simply return the result of $match: { type: "public" }. And yes you could chain together multiple $matches and $sorts. That's the idea of the aggregation "pipeline" is to make incremental changes to the data to get the result you want. Elaborate on what you want to do with the result of $match: { type: "public" } and I'll see if I can help find a solution.

Comment: In my example, I do [step 1] is,  
publicUsers = db.catagory.distinct(user, {type:'public'}),  
that is operate in [catagory collection].  

Then [step 2], I operate in [post collection],  
db.post.aggregate({$match: {user: {$in: publicUsers }}}, {$sort: {_id:-1}}, {$limit: 10}]),   
that will return the newest 10 post.  

My question is: can I write the [step 1] in aggregate? I do not know which command can do this.

Comment: Ok I've modified my answer again, give that a try. If that still isn't the solution you're looking for, then either I don't have enough information about how your database is built, or I'm not understanding what you're looking for.
So if you still need something else, try the aggregation pipeline build in MongoDB's Compass software. Open the collection in question and you'll see an Aggregations tab at the top. It makes it really easy to build the stages you need and see the result immediately.

Comment: Very thanks for your detailed answer. I've modified my question about the output result. That is most different part, I need output document list of posts, not post of somebody in his array. And finally, the post would be sort by time or id. It's a very different structure. The output mostly like a explore page, the posts of specific user will be list in the timeline.

Comment: So do you want: 

A. _only_ the public posts sorted from newest to oldest of one specific user that you can pass into the operation as a variable?

or

B. The public posts of _all_ users sorted from newest to oldest in a single array?

Comment: Yeah, B. All the posts of the public users, and sorted.

Comment: Alright I've added one last pipeline for you to try. I also added a few more suggestions for optimizing your queries in the list at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I do it like this.

```
db.post.aggregate([
    {$match:{
        uid:{$in: db.catagory.distinct('id',{type:'public'})}  # directly write here
        _id:{$lt: ObjectId("5c6d5494b9f43f020d4122a0")}        # for turn the page
    }},
    {$sort:{_id:-1}},  # sort by post _id
    {$limit:20}        # page size
])
```

It's faster than lookup or others.